# delete pandas row on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DF

```
     id      number      score          
0   J62      002         100.20         
1   J62      002         8.23           
2   M23      002         36.207         
3   M23      004         83.25
```

If the combination of id and number are duplicated then the row with least score will be deleted. output should be

```
     id      number      score          
0   J62      002         100.20         
1   M23      002         36.207         
2   M23      004         83.25
```

How can it be done using pandas ?

EDIT

Mysolution

df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['id', 'number']).reset_index(drop=True)

Please let me know of better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Below code would help you

```
res = df[df['score'].isin(df.groupby(['id','number']).max()['score'].values)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
  id      number      score          
0   J62      002         100.20         
1   M23      002         36.207         
2   M23      004         83.25
```

Answer (score 0):

This should capture all scenerios

```
    m=df.score.isin(df.groupby(["id", "number"], as_index=False)["score"].min()['score'])
    m1=df.duplicated(subset=['id','number'], keep=False)
    df[~(m&m1)]
```